# Addding dynamicly id to page block

Tags: visualforce

Giving me error multipal annotation

apex:pageBlock id="{!pageblocksectionid}"

how can i add ?

Answer (score 1):

Part of the design of Visualforce is that the `id` fields in Visualforce cannot be expressions: they must be constants. I don't know the reason for this limitation. Often Visualforce removes the need for the expressions. For example in an `apex:pageBlockTable`, a row index is automatically included in the `id` value generated in the HTML page, ensuring the HTML `id` values are unique as they need to be.

Are you sure you need to use an expression?

Usually you can restructure the problem to eliminate the need for varying the `id` value. Or put the variation in some other attribute such as the style class or a [pass through attribute](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_html_features_pass_through_attributes.htm). Tools like jQuery have convenient [selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp) for things other than the `id` value.